# Footer in the mobile version is not going to the bottom(Desktop version seems fine) - Javascript/ReactJS/CSS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass, responsive-design

i am a bit confused with the CSS for my project, every time i try to adjust the `footer` it works   fine in  `desktop version` but not in `mobile version`.   the issue i am facing is the the footer is not at the bottom of the page, if i try to adjust the height in the footer or if i change the `bottom to 0`  it will then take the footer out of sight on the desktop version`(i.e  vertical scroll bar appears)`, not sure what i am missing here.

any suggestion/pointers appreciated.

**Note:** i want to keep the position relative as when the number of content increases i want to make the footer move to downwards.

- `Deployed version` https://yogaoutlet.herokuapp.com/
- `Snippet of Code` from the footer component in React

```
  return (
    <div className="footer" style={{ msOverflowY: "hidden" }}>
      <div className="container" style={{ height: "13rem", width: "100vh", minMarginLeft: "0.1%", paddingTop: "1%" }}>
        <div className="row" style={{ display: "inlineFlex", marginTop: "0.5em", width: "100%" }}>
          {/* colum 1 */}
          <div className="col" style={{ maxWidth: "16rem" }}>
            <h4> Yogaoutlet Ltd</h4>
            <ul className="list-unstyled">
              <li>(+44) 123-123-1234</li>
              <li> 123 street London road</li>
              <li>London, UK</li>
            </ul>
          </div>

          {/* colum 2 */}

          <div className="col" style={{ maxWidth: "25rem" }}>
            <h4> ABOUT US</h4>
            <ul className="list-unstyled">
              <li> Terms of Use</li>
              <li>Privacy Policy</li>
              <li>Accessibility Statement</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          {/* colum 3 */}
          <div></div>

          <div className="col" style={{ maxWidth: "45rem", maxMarginLeft: "20%" }}>
            <h4> SIGN UP FOR EMAIL</h4>
            <ul className="list-unstyled">
              <li>For yoga updates, offers, news and promotions</li>
              <li>
                {
                  <form style={{ postion: "block" }} onSubmit={signupEmail} className="input-group">
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      placeholder="Enter here your email"
                      id="forSignupemail"
                      class="form-control inputBlock"
                      name="emailForSignupOnly"
                      value={name}
                      onChange={updatesignupEmail}
                      style={{ maxWidth: "19rem" }}
                    />
                    <ButtonGroup>
                      <Button className="btn buttonBlock" variant="primary" type="submit">
                        SIGNUP
                      </Button>
                    </ButtonGroup>
                  </form>
                }
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>

        <hr style={{ padding: "0", margin: "0" }} />
        <div className="row" style={{ height: "2rem", marginTop: "0" }}>
          <p className="col-sm">@copy;{new Date().getFullYear()} Yogaoutlet Ltd | ALL right reserved | Terms of Service | Privacy</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

-`Snippet of CSS` for footer

```
.footer {
  /* margin-top: 1rem; */
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  grid-area: footer;
  background: rgb(73, 79, 82);
  color: #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
  /* align-items: center;
  justify-content: center; */
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  bottom: 7em;
  height: 14rem;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;

  width: 100%;
  min-width: 480px;
}
```

- `GitHub Code` link for the complete code  [GitHub coder link](https://github.com/rock-007/JavaScript-Project/tree/master/E-commerece-project/client/src)

-`Photo of the mobile version`

[image]

-`after setting bottom=0`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use absolute position for the footer and position it at bottom 0. The height of the body can be anything but if you use `bottom: 0` you can get the footer to always be at bottom

Below is a working example for this

```css
html,
body {
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   height:100%;
}

div {
    outline: 1px solid;
}
#container {
   min-height:100%;
   position:relative;
}
#content {
   height: 1000px; /* Changed this height */
   padding-bottom:60px;
   background: #eee;
}
#footer {
   position:absolute;
   bottom:0;
   width:100%;
   height:60px;
   background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
   <div id="content">your page content.  set to 1000 px for example</div>
   <div id="footer">Footer will always be at the bottom</div>
</div>
```

Take out this line in your css and you see it works
[image]

Comment: i tried to replicate this code including setting `bottom:0` but its its not working. not sure what else i can do

Comment: do me a favor. Can you inspect your footer element and see what the css properties of `footer` is in the browser?

Comment: Do you still have this line `bottom: 7em` in your css for footer? Aslo - Unrelated to your problem but the width of iphone is `375`, why are you using `min-width: 480px`.

Comment: See updated working version of your site in my answer

Comment: Thanks, I didn't changed in  the deployed version but i have tried in the browser and checked it but it didnt work though it bough footer a bit down but still i can see there is bootom gap, i have updated the screenshot above, also ,I have live deployed version at `https://yogaoutlet.herokuapp.com/`,  if that helps

Comment: just saw your updated screenshot. did you try taking out bottom altogether?

Comment: i have set bottom to zero and also uncheck as well but its the same, foot moves a bit down but not at the bottom

Comment: are you seeing the same if you open in your browser, i guess.

Comment: I added a screenshot of what I see in the browser. Footer is stuck to the bottom after making the change I suggested. Not sure what else I can do to show it works.

Comment: Thanks Kal, for the reply , i dont know what exactly i am missing, whith bit more tweak i can bring down in the mobile version but when i switch to desktop version the footer goes quite up there, may i ask one mor ething please, so in your machine it shows correct in the mobile version but is it remain the same when you switch back to desktop version?

Comment: I just looked again i can see your point, you keeping the position to absolute, but in my case i need to keep it relative all the time as when i need to display multiple items(fetch from backend) i want the footer to go down

Comment: That was not clear in your question. Then you need to use `position: fixed`